# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

This is my installed app.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    'corsheaders',
    'articles',
]
```

I am using django 2.1 and rest framework.I want to implement rest auth registration. So I have followed this step by step guidelines from official [documentation](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). When I hit enter the migrate command `python manage.py migrate`
I am getting following error:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before migrate you need to install the django rest auth packages which contain all 
 packages including **allauth**

```
pip install django-rest-auth[with_social]
```

and then migrate your database.

Comment: I have installed the package but I did not include the [with_social]. I have now installed with pip install django-rest-auth[with_social] and my database is now migrate. Thanks for your help.